# AngularJS - Submit button not disabling (im a newbie)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, attributes, angularjs-ng-disabled

I know I'm doing something wrong, but here is the code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="false" value="Not Disabled"/> <!-- Shouldn't be disabled -->
    <br>
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="true" value="Disabled"/> <!-- Should be disabled -->
</form>
```

Why isn't the second submit button disabled? I searched online and I thought you could use ng-disabled to have a boolean as the disabled attribute.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button will only be disabled if the expression evaluates to true and the parent element has the `ng-app` attribute.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="false" value="Not Disabled"/> <!-- Shouldn't be disabled -->
    <br>
    <div ng-app ng-init="disableBtn=true">
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="disableBtn" value="Disabled"/> <!-- Should be disabled -->
</div>
    
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I will tick your answer as soon as I can (I need to wait 10 minutes)

Comment: @MBJH No problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code needs an `ng-app` directive to boot AngularJS. Otherwise the `ng-disabled` directive will not be compiled:

```
̶<̶f̶o̶r̶m̶>̶
<form ng-app>
```

### The DEMO

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<form ng-app>
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="false" value="Not Disabled"/> <!-- Shouldn't be disabled -->
    <br>
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="true" value="Disabled"/> <!-- Should be disabled -->
</form>
```